# First class functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading an article on SitePoint (https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/) and there is an example of a first class function:

```
var foo = function() {
 console.log("Hello World!");
};
var bar = function(arg) {
return arg;
};
bar(foo)();
```

The syntax of the last line looks puzzling to me, and I would have written it as:

```
bar(foo());
```

Does anyone know if either syntax is ok, or if there is a good reason for writing it the way the article wrote it? If so, please explain what that reason is.

Thanks,

William

Comment: The difference between the two is what actually makes functions *first class* in JS. The example on the site illustrates the fact that a function is a data type that can be passed around, not just called. I think this article will clear things up for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know if either syntax is ok,

There are completely different.

`bar(foo)()` calls bar, passing it foo as an argument, gets the return value of bar and then calls that return value as a function.

`bar(foo())` calls foo, gets the return value of foo, then calls bar, passing it the return value of foo as an argument.

> there is a good reason for writing it the way the article wrote it

It's a completely contrived example. There's no practical reason to involve bar in this at all. It is just showing that you can pass a function about like any other value (which your version doesn't do).

Comment: Just a comment on you "there's no practical reason". That's a theoretical example, so the reasoning is purely theoretical.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru — Yes, that's what the previous sentence and the next sentence mean.

Comment: Not arguing, just trying to emphasize the part I think is most important.

Answer (score 0):

The term "first class functions" can typically be thought of as the ability to pass functions around the same way you would variables.

The last example is taking `foo`, which is a function, and passing it into `bar()`, another function. `bar()` returns yet another function and that is being called immediately after, hence the extra `()` at the end. So the way the example was written was not just a stylistic approach; it is showing how functions can be passed around, even into other functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
bar(foo)();
```

Calls the function bar, using foo (a function, not the return value of the function) as the argument. Since bar returns the argument, bar ends up returning a function. Adding () at the end causes the returned function to be executed.

```
bar(foo());
```

Calls the function bar, using the return value of foo() as the argument

The reason why the code example shows a function being passed as an argument to another function, and being returned from the function is to showcase that functions are objects and can be passed around like one.

Answer (score 0):

The two are fundamentally different and would achieve different things. Let's look at both.

```
bar(foo)();
```

This passes a **reference** to the function `bar` as the only argument to the function `bar`, which promptly returns the passed function as the return value, which is then executed via the final `()`.

Essentially, it's a laborious way of executing `foo`.

```
bar(foo());
```

This first executes `foo` and passes the return value - which is nothing - as the only argument to `bar`. Nothing further happens.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be the same, but what the two syntax do are different. When writing `bar(foo)();`, `bar` *returns a function* and then you call this function. It means:

- `arg` in the body of the `bar` method hold a reference to `foo`;
- `bar` is executed before `foo`;
- `bar` returns a function.

Writing `bar(foo())`, you first call `foo` and then pass its result to bar. It means:

- `arg` in the body of the `bar` method holds a reference to the string `"Hello World"`
- `foo` is called first
- `bar` returns a string

Answer (score 0):

When you write `foo`, you are referencing the function `foo`, not the value that this function returns. The function is not executed.

When you write `foo()`, you are executing the function and returning it's value.

So, when you say `bar(foo)()`, you are passing a *function* `foo` as an argument to `bar`. Since `bar` returns any argument it receives, this time it returns the function `foo`, and then it is being executed.

To simplify, this is what is happening:

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
};

var bar = function(arg) {
  return arg;
};

var returnFromBar = bar(foo);
returnFromBar();
```